# How do you indent *every* line of a <span> element?

Tags: css, lines, indentation

I have the following HTML chunk:

```
<span class='instruction_text'>
  Line 1<br>
  Line 2
</span>
```

And the CSS declaration of instruction_text is:

```
.instruction_text {
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #555;
}
```

The first line has a `70px` margin as expected, but the next line starts with no indent. How can I make ALL of the lines indented?

Comment: style="display: inline-block;  margin: 0 50px 0 50px; worked for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a block-level element.  `<div>` is block-level by default, but adding the CSS `display:block` to your `instruction_text` class should send you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Using BR tags inside a SPAN element doesn't make a lot of sense as SPAN in an inline element which means it's meant to be used in the flow of a line of text or other inline elements.

You really should be using an element that is a "block" level element like DIV or P, e.g. one that is designed to contain multiple lines of text (or inline elements).

As you'll have noticed, you CAN use a BR tag inside a SPAN and it will cause a line break, however inline elements don't play well with margins/padding etc.

Comment: Looks like somebody got there first.

Comment: I forgot `span` was an inline element.